# Is it a good practice to use database queries in helper functions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dry

I've used database queries in helper functions in the CodeIgniter framework.

Suppose, a database has many tables, e.g. *school*, *student*, ... etc. and there are common tasks are required in the application, such as generating random unique ids for each entry into a table, retrieving an entire row of the matched row from a table, ... etc. are required.

Now, we can write functions for each task in the respective models of the database, e.g.

In *School_model* :

```
class School_model extends CI_Model
{
    // some code ...    

    function generateID()
    {
        // code to generate unique id by checking the database
    }

    // some code ...
}
```

and in *Student_model* :

```
class Student_model extends CI_Model
{
    // some code ...    

    function generateID()
    {
        // same code to generate unique id except the table name
    }

    // some code ...
}
```

**Or** we can pass the *table_name* as an argument to a helper function as:

```
function generate_ID( $table_name )
{
    // code to genetrate unique id by checking in $table_name
}
```

The later prevants code duplication ( DRY ). But is it a good practice to use database queries in functions outside the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, extending Codeigniter core is the better approach for this.

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
```

You can write the `function generate_ID( $table_name ){` inside core model

Finally extend your model with MY_Model

```
class Student_model extends MY_Model
```